# Combine two power sources with higher priority for one source

Tags: solar-energy

I have two power sources, one is solar panels (DC), another is from grid (AC). Is it possible to combine these two power sources with solar getting higher priority ? By high priority I mean draw power from grid only if solar is not sufficient or absent. Final output is required to be AC

One way would be to convert grid ac to dc, matched to dc output of solar panels, and then some how combine them (with priority for solar) and then convert back to AC.

Grid-tie setup is not possible. Also Grid is too unstable (not available every 3rd or 4th hour) so I am going to need batteries any way. I want to prioritize use of power sources in this way:

1. Solar
2. Grid
3. Batteries.

So if solar is not sufficient it should tap grid (if available) for deficit power else it should use batteries. I want to minimize cycling of batteries and use only as a last resort.

I have come across a [Taiwanese product](http://www.voltronicpower.com/oCart2/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=132) which supports solar first, then battery and lastly Grid. Manual states that You can set the discharge voltage level of battery at which point it will point back to grid until batteries are fully charged then back to batteries and so on.

Maybe I am being too conservative with cycling of batteries. I would like to know if use of batteries only as a backup is possible given my required priorities.

[This question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/117554/51760) uses only one source at the a time but I want to use both sources at the same time such that if solar is insufficient, don't turn it off, rather augment it with grid. For example if solar can deliver 2 Amps and I need 5 amps in total, I want a way to be able to draw remaining 3 amps from the grid. And if load requires 2 amps, stop taking from grid. Is it possible ?

For simplification lets assume grid also supplies in DC. Also I have some controller d1 connected with Panels which convert output of panels to 24v dc and another device d2 to convert grid to 24v dc as well. I want to combine d1 and d2 to add currents with above mentioned priorities.

Comment: I'm sure this is already done everywhere....

Comment: The better way is to convert soalr panel energy to AC. If your home does not use all the solar power, the remaining power is sold to the grid. If the solar power does not meet your consumption, you buy what is needed from the grid. That is state of the art.

Comment: Not a duplicate.  A solar panel is nothing like a battery or power supply.

Comment: You can't just 'combine' two DC sources without matching the voltage. And you can't match the voltage of a solar cell without controlling the source current.

Comment: Uwe is correct: get yourself a "grid-tied" inverter and it will sort this out for you. Depending where you are you should be able to get paid for electricity generated through a "feed in tarriff" or "net metering".

Answer (score 1):

Not well without a battery. Solar panels are best used with a battery.  The problem is not in the switching but it will switch too often.

The battery will help with the momentary outage such as a cloud. Ideally you only want it to switch when the sun rises and sets.

You can use the inverter's output to power a relay with normally open (utility AC side source) and and normally closed contacts (inverter side source). When the inverter can no longer provide power the relay will will deactivate and switch the power source.  When the inverter's power is back on it will activate the relay switching back to the solar power.